# Vbscript error handing

Tags: vba, vbscript, error-handling

I have a vbscript that sends a post command to a website and collects data.
The problem I have is that sometimes the webpage becomes unavailable and the vbscript ends with an error: 800C0005 "The system cannot locate the resource specified"

With some search I have been trying to use the code below, but hasn't been working

```
Dim xmlhttp
Set xmlhttp = createobject("msxml2.xmlhttp.6.0")

xmlhttp.open "post", "https://website.com", False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.send
Get_HTML = xmlhttp.responsetext

On Error Resume Next

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Err.Clear
End If
```

Comment: it looks like you are clearing out the errors when you have one

Comment: That's the plan I would like to clear the error, wait a bit and then try again

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: Added the code, when the page is unavailable the script ends with error on the "xmlhttp.send"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to retry an operation in case of an error you need to put the `OERN` before the operation, add some delay when you got an error, and wrap the whole thing in a loop:

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")

On Error Resume Next
Do
  Err.Clear  'clear whatever error you had in the last iteration

  xmlhttp.open "POST", "https://website.com", False
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  xmlhttp.send
  Get_HTML = xmlhttp.responseText

  If Err Then WScript.Sleep 2000  'wait 2 seconds after an error occurred
Loop While Err
On Error Goto 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the position of `On Error Resume Next` to execute before executing the `xmlhttp.open` request.

```
Dim xmlhttp
Set xmlhttp = createobject("msxml2.xmlhttp.6.0")

On Error Resume Next

xmlhttp.open "post", "https://website.com", False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.send
Get_HTML = xmlhttp.responsetext

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  'Code for how you want to handle the error, if you want to handle it at all
End If
```